# Laravel passport not loading private key properly

Tags: laravel

I have installed Laravel passport, and it's working fine on my local machine.

I don't want to have to run a passport command on the server so what I've done is tried to load the passport keys from the environment according to the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#loading-keys-from-the-environment.

I ran the publish command locally:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config
```

Then I simply deployed the config file that was produced.

I can see that passport is trying to use that variable, because I'm getting this error in my php logs:

```
dev.ERROR: Key path “file://-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY--- foo -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----” does not exist or is not readable at /var/www/overwatch/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php:52)”
```

It looks to me like it is trying to read my key string as a file, but the docs don't seem to suggest anything else.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: If you have `Passport::loadKeysFrom` in your service provider, remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I checked but it's not there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment file was using ' rather than ". Changing this fixed the issue.